# Dropdown hover not working

Tags: html, css

I want the list to display when you hover on the a link. Yet it doesnt work.

See snippets below:

```css
.assist-label:hover .assist-list {
  display: block;
}

.assist-list {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #141825;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-assist-container">
  <a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant</a>
  <ul class="assist-list">
    <li class="assist-item" id="carWorth">Car Worth</li>
    <li class="assist-item browse">
      Browse
      <ul class="browse-list">
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseMake">Makes</li>
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseType">Types</li>
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseYear">Year</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="assist-item">Compare</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this structure

```
<a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant</a>
        <ul class="assist-list">
```

This

```
.assist-label:hover .assist-list{
   display: block;
  }
```

will not work because `.assist-list` is **not a child of `assist-label`...it's a sibling**

You want

```
.assist-label:hover + .assist-list{
       display: block;
      }
```

using the *adjacent sibling* selector.

Note: You will also have to amend the opacity of the list on hover.

```css
.assist-label:hover+.assist-list {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.assist-list {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #141825;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-assist-container">
  <a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant</a>
  <ul class="assist-list">
    <li class="assist-item" id="carWorth">Car Worth</li>
    <li class="assist-item browse">
      Browse
      <ul class="browse-list">
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseMake">Makes</li>
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseType">Types</li>
        <li class="browse-item" id="browseYear">Year</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="assist-item">Compare</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Can I ask why this only works with the display property. If I remove that and just make it use opacity. It doesn't work. How should I structure the html dropdown then?

Comment: It depends on what it is you are trying to do. Menus like this are usually positioned so they don't affect the layout of other items.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work by wrapping the a link around the list. Thank you Paulie.